# How do I add text in front of each item of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this piece of code which goes through all elements containing the class "menu-item-li" and puts the value of their href tags inside an array. This is the code to do so:

```
var arr = new Array();
$(".menu-item-li").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

These would return things like:

- link1.html
- link2.html
- link3.html
- ...and so on

Now what I want to do, is put some text in front of each item in the array. Say I want to put "website/" in front of each item. The result should be like this:

- website/link1.html
- website/link2.html
- website/link3.html
- ...and so on

How do I edit my Javascript code so that I can add "website/" to the front of each item inside the array?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr.push('website/' + $(this).attr("href"));`, but you could also use `.map` method.

```
var arr = $(".menu-item-li").map(function() {
    return 'website/' + $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick! Oh and, I do use jQuery. Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: Ah yeah, don't forget about `.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = new Array();
$(".menu-item-li").each(function() {
    var str = "website/"+$(this).attr("href");
    arr.push(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array contains a list of `<a>` elements – I'm assuming that despite the class name because you're using `href` property – then it simply:

```
var arr = $(".menu-item-li").map(function() {
    return "website/" + this.href;
});
```

You actually don't need to call again jQuery on `this` and call the `attr` method, it's a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
var arr = new Array();
$(".menu-item-li").each(function() {
    arr.push('website/' + $(this).attr("href"));
});
```